# Insert new response in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have two json's Response

```
{
    "response": "00",
    "data": {
        "Tanggal": "20191118",
        "Jam": "144632",
        "DestinationName": "NANDA FERNANDO",
        "message": "Inquiry success"
    }
}
```

Second one response is

```
{
   "balance" : "1000000"
}
```

I want to merge them and have a json like

```
{
    "response": "00",
    "data": {
        "Tanggal": "20191118",
        "Jam": "144632",
        "DestinationName": "NANDA FERNANDO",
        "message": "Inquiry success",
        "Balance" : "1000000"
    }
}
```

Code

```
 $ini = json_encode(array_merge(json_decode($response, true),$b));
```

the response like this

```
{
    "response": "00",
    "data": {
        "Tanggal": "20191118",
        "Jam": "145541",
        "DestinationAcc": "7001520304",
        "DestinationName": "NANDA FERNANDO",
        "MsgKey": "88dc9a20",
        "message": "Inquiry success"
    },
    "balance": "1000000"
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your best effort.

Comment: `json_decode`, `array_merge`, `json_encode`

Comment: @brinardi this is what you want isn't it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use  `json_decode()`,`array_merge()` and then `json_encode()`:

```
<?php

$json = '{
    "response": "00",
    "data": {
        "Tanggal": "20191118",
        "Jam": "144632",
        "DestinationName": "NANDA FERNANDO",
        "message": "Inquiry success"
    }
}';

$json2 = '{
   "balance" : "1000000"
}';

$arr1 = json_decode($json, true);
$arr2 = json_decode($json2, true);


$arr1['data'] = array_merge($arr1['data'], $arr2);

$data = json_encode($arr1);

echo $data;
```

Output: https://3v4l.org/bBiis

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can get an idea from this.

```
    var json1 = '{
        "response": "00",
        "data": {
            "Tanggal": "20191118",
            "Jam": "144632",
            "DestinationName": "NANDA FERNANDO",
            "message": "Inquiry success"
        }
    }';

   var json2 = '{
       "balance" : "1000000"
    }';

    for (var key in json2) {
        json1[key] = json2[key]
    }

    var response = JSON.stringify(json1);
    alert(response);
```

Comment: Think OP wanted the answer in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I see what you are trying to achieve is already achieved , but you want to show it pretty view ( like you snippet ) right ? 
you can use JSON_PRETTY_PRINT for that.

This can be simplified more, but for your better understanding,

here it is.

```
$json = '{
    "response": "00",
    "data": {
        "Tanggal": "20191118",
        "Jam": "144632",
        "DestinationName": "NANDA FERNANDO",
        "message": "Inquiry success"
    }
}';

$json2 = '{
   "balance" : "1000000"
}';

$arr1 = json_decode($json, true);
$arr2 = json_decode($json2, true);


$arr = array_merge($arr1, $arr2);

$json_string = json_encode($arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

echo $json_string;
```

However JSON isn't supposed to contain HTML line breaks, whereas newline characters are valid in JSON. If you want to display JSON on a web page then do a string replacement on the newline characters yourself or else put the JSON in a < pre > element. See json.org for the syntax reference.

Comment: <pre> ... </pre> element